# What's wrong with running this server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've managed to make a new rails project skeleton with no problems. However, when I tried to run the rails server, it doesn't work. I've included a log below for what's happening.

```
stanley@ubuntu:~$ rails new railstest
       exist  
   identical  README.rdoc
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  config.ru
   identical  .gitignore
   identical  Gemfile
       exist  app
   identical  app/assets/images/rails.png
   identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
   identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
       exist  app/mailers
       exist  app/models
   identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
   identical  app/mailers/.gitkeep
   identical  app/models/.gitkeep
       exist  config
   identical  config/routes.rb
   identical  config/application.rb
   identical  config/environment.rb
       exist  config/environments
   identical  config/environments/development.rb
   identical  config/environments/production.rb
   identical  config/environments/test.rb
       exist  config/initializers
   identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
   identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
   identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
Overwrite /home/stanley/railstest/config/initializers/secret_token.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
       force  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
   identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb
   identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
       exist  config/locales
   identical  config/locales/en.yml
   identical  config/boot.rb
   identical  config/database.yml
       exist  db
   identical  db/seeds.rb
       exist  doc
   identical  doc/README_FOR_APP
       exist  lib
       exist  lib/tasks
   identical  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
       exist  lib/assets
   identical  lib/assets/.gitkeep
       exist  log
   identical  log/.gitkeep
       exist  public
   identical  public/404.html
   identical  public/422.html
   identical  public/500.html
   identical  public/favicon.ico
   identical  public/index.html
   identical  public/robots.txt
       exist  script
   identical  script/rails
       exist  test/fixtures
   identical  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
       exist  test/functional
   identical  test/functional/.gitkeep
       exist  test/integration
   identical  test/integration/.gitkeep
       exist  test/unit
   identical  test/unit/.gitkeep
   identical  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
   identical  test/test_helper.rb
       exist  tmp/cache
       exist  tmp/cache/assets
       exist  vendor/assets/javascripts
   identical  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
       exist  vendor/assets/stylesheets
   identical  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
       exist  vendor/plugins
   identical  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.5) 
Using activesupport (3.2.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.3) 
Using mime-types (1.18) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.3) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.3) 
Using activeresource (3.2.3) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.3.3) 
Using execjs (1.3.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.3) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.3) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.2) 
Using bundler (1.1.3) 
Using rails (3.2.3) 
Using sass (3.1.18) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.5) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using uglifier (1.2.4) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
stanley@ubuntu:~$ cd railstest/
stanley@ubuntu:~/railstest$ rails server
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-1.3.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:50:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/execjs-1.3.2/lib/execjs.rb:5
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
    from /home/stanley/railstest/config/application.rb:7
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Thanks in advance for your feedback on what's happening!

Comment: very bad question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line to fix your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Later version of rails requires a javascript runtime environment, and this can be fixed by multiple solutions, install nodejs on ubuntu is one of the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it was related to nodejs.

Comment: You can use "gem 'therubyracer'". Node.js is better solution